# How to send automatic notification from firebase whenever a new child is added

Tags: android, firebase

I'm developing an Android Recipe app. I want to send push notification from firebase whenever a new recipe is added but I'm unable to find out how to do that. If anybody knows the solution please let me know your help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make functions and upload it to firebase console via command prompt and by using firebase CLI (Command Line Interface).

If you're using firebase firestore as database please refer [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xkA53Ga6R1k) link else

if you're using realtime database please refer [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=voIFz8aE9eE&t=3s) link.

Hope it helps.